# How can I make a dynamic variable?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a little question, which I am unable to solve;

I've got one div, which onTouchEnd should run a little jquery code (which it does perfectly).
When running this function, it will send the ID of the particular div.

```
<div id="tapme1" class="subject hold" onTouchEnd="goes(this.id)"></div>
```

It runs this function:

```
function goes(e) {
   var now = new Date().getTime();
   var lastTouch = $(this).data('lastTouch') || now + 1 /** the first time this will make delta a negative number */;
   var lement = e
   var delta = now - lastTouch;
   if(delta<300 && delta>0) {
      if($('#tapme1').hasClass("hold")) {
          $('#tapme1').removeClass("hold");
      }
      else {
      $('#tapme1').addClass("hold");
      }
   }
   else {
      // A click/touch action could be invoked here but we need to wait half a second before doing so.
   }
   $(this).data('lastTouch', now);
}
function goes(e) {
   var now = new Date().getTime();
   var lastTouch = $(this).data('lastTouch') || now + 1 /** the first time this will make delta a negative number */;
   var lement = e
   var delta = now - lastTouch;
   if(delta<300 && delta>0){
      if($('#tapme1').hasClass("hold")) {
          $('#tapme1').removeClass("hold");
      }
      else {
           $('#tapme1').addClass("hold");
      }
    }
    else {
       // A click/touch action could be invoked here but we need to wait half a second before doing so.
    }
    $(this).data('lastTouch', now);
}
```

As you can tell, this works perfectly. Now comes the problem. I want it to change the div which is clicked. When I turned `$('#tapme1')` into `$(lement)` it didn't do a thing. I've tried numerous possibilities.

Hoping any of you can help me with this, appreciated!

Comment: Please tidy up the code. It is too messy and the indents make it difficult to follow: so I just stopped reading. Coding is also about *hubris*.

Comment: Maybe a copy/paste error, but you've got the goes function twice there. Also, you're lacking a semicolon after var lement = e.

Comment: @OllyHodgson A semicolon is not required there ;-) (I write semicolon-free, however I agree in that lacking it is *inconsistent* with the chosen style.)

Comment: @pst Indeed. It's not required, but they're using them everywhere else :)

Comment: Edited the code, it sure needs tidying up. Thanks for the quick replies! (and thanks to Ran for tidying up :P)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `#` before the id selector.

Change `$(lement)` to `$("#" + lement)`

Comment: Might I add, this is exaclty the problem I've been running into, you have just saved my day mister. Thanks you (:

Answer (score 1):

You have to use :
    $('#' + lement)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `'#'`

change it to:

```
$('#' + lement)
```

instead of:

```
$(lement)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you send only `this` instead of `this.id` as paramater?

```
<div id="tapme1" class="subject hold" onTouchEnd="goes(this)"></div>
```

than you can use

```
$(lement)
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of that? Much cleaner!

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the id, e.g. `tapme1`. jQuery wants a CSS selector, e.g. `#tapme1`. So change your code to look for `$("#"+lement)`, or even better, `var lement = "#" + e;`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already passing `id`, you will have to change:

```
$('#tapme1')
```

To:

```
$('#' + lement)
```

`lement` being the argument of your function eg the `id` you are passing.